# InvalidOperation in T4 Generated Helper Method SelfTrackingModel.Context.Extensions

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, poco, self-tracking-entities

I have a project whereby I'm using STE's (EF4.1) and I'm hitting a reproducable issue when I call the auto generated ApplyChanges() method on one of my object sets, passing in an object graph I have held in memory, and I'm getting the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: 
    Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

This is originating from within a call to ObjectContext.AddObject() method, which is being called by the T4 auto generated ApplyChanges() method. My method to call ApplyChanges looks something like this:

```
// Extension to auto generated Session : IObjectWithChangeTracker
public partial class Session
{
    public void SaveToDatabase(String myConnectionString)
    { 
        using (MyContext DbContext = new MyContext(myConnectionString))
        {
            DbContext.Sessions.ApplyChanges(this);
            DbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The call stack when I hit the error looks something like this:

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.WalkObjectGraphToIncludeAllRelatedEntities(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
... // The below 4 lines are pretty much repeated as it iterates through the object graph
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.WalkObjectGraphToIncludeAllRelatedEntities(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.WalkObjectGraphToIncludeAllRelatedEntities(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.AddRelatedEntitiesToObjectStateManager(Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AddObject(String entitySetName, Object entity)
at MyNamespace.SelfTrackingEntitiesContextExtensions.AddHelper.AddAllEntities(ObjectContext context, String entitySetName, IObjectWithChangeTracker entity)
at MyNamespace.SelfTrackingEntitiesContextExtensions.ApplyChanges[TEntity](ObjectContext context, String entitySetName, TEntity entity)
at MyNamespace.SelfTrackingEntitiesContextExtensions.ApplyChanges[TEntity](ObjectSet`1 objectSet, TEntity entity) 
at MyNamespace.Transaction.SaveToDatabase(String transactionDbConnectionString)
```

I'm not modifying the object graph at all whilst the operation is in progress, so I'm really stumped as to the issue. Anybody got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. 
We could solve it with removing Navigation properties so that they cannot run in circles. 
So if A has B as a Navigation Property, B should not hav A as a Navigation property. 
It is not possible under all circumstances but in our case, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Looks like a bug that was fixed in .net 4.5.